# Why does Python ignore my input and skip my if statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, input

Python seems to skip my if statement.

```
is_hot = ""
true_or_false = input("True or False? ").lower()

if true_or_false == "true":
    is_hot == True
elif true_or_false == "false":
    is_hot == False
else:
    print("You didn't type true or false")

#The skipped if statement:
if is_hot == True:
    print("It's a hot day")
    print("Drink water.")
elif is_hot == False:
    print("It's not hot.")

print("Enjoy your day")
```

The output is just the last print statement.

Comment: Please post the full output of a program run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is with the assignment to `is_hot`.

change:

```
if true_or_false == "true":
    is_hot == True
elif true_or_false == "false":
    is_hot == False
```

to:

```
if true_or_false == "true":
    is_hot = True
elif true_or_false == "false":
    is_hot = False
```

Notice the single `=`? That means an assignment whereas `==` means comparison.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am still learning. Thank you!

Comment: @ConstantinShimonenko Nothing to be sorry about! You are learning something new and this is brilliant! Don't worry about such things, you will master them soon enough, Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It should just be a single = instead of == for `is_hot`